# Implement repeating fields in a Thymeleaf web form

Tags: arrays, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a form I'd like to create with 12 fields and each field can accept between 0 and 15 entries. This is to collect tax information for a tax payer's vehicles (which could be none, or multiple).

I've developed this object:

```
protected String[] carMakeModel;
protected String[] carCO2EmissionsFigure;
protected String[] carFuelType;
protected String[] carIdentifier;
protected String[] carAmendmentIndicator;
protected Date[] carDateCarWasAvailableFrom;
protected Date[] carDateCarWasAvailableTo;
protected Date[] carDateFreeFuelProvided;
protected Date[] carDateFreeFuelWasWithdrawn;
protected String[] carCalculatedPricePence;
protected String[] carCashEquivalentofCarPence;
protected String[] carCashEquivalentofFuelPence;
```

You can see that I have chosen to use arrays to accept the multiple entries. Is this correct or wrong?

These are not the only fields on the form, there are many that only accept a  single entry so they are not arrays, and I already got them working fine.

I was debating if it would be better for me to create a Car object to include in this object? But then I would end up having to do it as an array anyway?

```
protected CarData[] carData;
```

So my real question is how would Thymeleaf handle these arrays? Or what is the alternative that works with Thymeleaf?

Comment: Thymeleaf works correctly with arrays or lists, so you wont have problems to handle your form data

Comment: Is the solution for me to write Javascript that packs the fields into an array? 

On the front end it just needs to be separate text boxes and date pickers and a button to click to add another set of them.

Comment: yes you can add that logic to the onSubmit method, the create and array or several, with the info you need and retrieve those arrays in your controller

Comment: Ok thanks so much. Sounds like it should all work nicely. I just wanted to check before putting in the work.